# How to set Not Null and Unique key constraint on a property from mvc model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

How can I apply not null and unique key constraint on a property from asp.net MVC model,

Below is my code:

```
public class Role
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Index("RoelsIndex",IsUnique=true)]        
    public string Roles { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Required not working for not null?

Comment: I am inserting record from sql server,At that time it is allowing null values and unique key is not applying.

Comment: do you use EF code first to generate the database?

Comment: Yes,I am using EF code first

Comment: if you use EF code first properly to generate the database, the not null constraint will be added into the column, and inserting from application will throw `DbEntityValidationException`

Comment: Ok,What about unique key?

Comment: Hi Madhu whats the problem this time?

Comment: If I include    [MaxLength(15)]    then it is working fine,For int type I didn't include    [MaxLength(11)]    it was worked but string type I included    [MaxLength(11)] then only working!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's your problem but Required and Index work fine when I try it.

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    [MaxLength(400)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class AppContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

[image: Result]